# Some values are not added to my dictionary from a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code

```
def query(q, L):
    result = []
    mDict = {}
    key = 0
    for x, i in enumerate(L):
        for y in i:
            if q == y:
                key += 1

        if q in i:
            result.append(x)
            mDict[key]=x

        key = 0

    print (mDict)
    print (result)
q = "h"
l = ["phone", "power", "high", "phones"]
query(q, l)
```

I am expecting my printed output to be

`{1: 0, 2: 2, 1: 3}`

`[0, 2, 3]`

but instead I am getting

`{1: 3, 2: 2}`

`[0, 2, 3]`

can anyone help me out?

Comment: keys in a dict are unique and cannot have two 1's in the same dict.

Comment: Please describe what function is supposed to do, beyond just the expected output for a single case.

Comment: thanks a lot. my values in the dictionary are unique, so I made my values key and key values like this mDict[x]=key and i got this {0: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1}
[0, 2, 3] as my result.

Comment: Please describe what function is supposed to do, beyond just the expected output for a single case

Comment: The function is suppose to take in a string q, and a list of strings L, and return a list of the indices of the String L that contains q as a substring. To get extra point I need to order the indices of the strings in L that contains q. For example query("h", ["phone", "power", "high", "phones"]) should return [2, 0, 3] for extra points. I was hoping if I could add the the indices and it's count in a dictionary, I could sort the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need complex functions to count characters in Python, you can use [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count).

And to collate the counts, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> q = "h"
>>> l = ["phone", "power", "high", "phones"]
>>> Counter(word.count(q) for word in l)
Counter({1: 2, 0: 1, 2: 1})
```

Comment: I noticed counter does not take in the indices of the string l, but rather increments when q is in l. It's suppose to return the indices in l and the count of q in l

Answer (score 0):

This code worked

```
q = "h"
L = ["phone", "power", "high", "phones"]

mDict = {}
values = 0
for x, i in enumerate(L):
    for y in i:
        if q == y:
            values += 1

    if q in i:
        mDict[x]=values

    values = 0

sorted_dict = sorted(mDict, key=mDict.get, reverse=True)

print (sorted_dict)
```

output

```
[2, 0, 3]
```